# Pass integers value to another activity by Intent. Dose not work

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to Android and trying to learn how to pass some variables from activity to another activity by Intents. The problem is when I run the app after finishing answering my questions it will take me to the Summary activity which has the result of the AskQusetions activity (the count of yes and no)

Here is my AskQuestion Activity:

```
    package com.example.quizapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AskQuestions extends Activity {

    private String[] messages;
    private int yesCount;
    private int noCount;
    private int messageNum;
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.quizapp.MESSAGE";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask_questions);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        messages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lblask_questions);
        messageNum = 0;
        setYesCount(0);
        setNoCount(0);

        TextView lblQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblask_questions);
        lblQuestion.setText(messages[messageNum]);
    }

    public void onYes(View view) {
        Log.i("Quiz App", "viewing next question");

        setYesCount(getYesCount() + 1); // count yes
        messageNum++;
        if (messageNum >= messages.length) { // if the questions finished got to summary
            // go to summary
            Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(this, Summary.class);
            //int messageYes = getYesCount();
            summaryIntent.putExtra("value", getYesCount());
            startActivity(summaryIntent);
        }

        TextView lblQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblask_questions);
        lblQuestion.setText(messages[messageNum]);
    }

    public void onNo(View view) {
        Log.i("Quiz App", "viewing next question");

        setNoCount(getNoCount() + 1); // count not
        messageNum++;
        if (messageNum >= messages.length) { // if the questions finished got to summary
            // go to summary
            Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(this, Summary.class);
            summaryIntent.putExtra("value", getNoCount()); 
            startActivity(summaryIntent);
        }



        TextView lblQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblask_questions);
        lblQuestion.setText(messages[messageNum]);
    }

    public int getYesCount() {
        return yesCount;
    }

    public void setYesCount(int yesCount) {
        this.yesCount = yesCount;
    }

    public int getNoCount() {
        return noCount;
    }

    public void setNoCount(int noCount) {
        this.noCount = noCount;
    }

}
```

Here is my Summary Activity:

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * @author ***
 *
 */
public class Summary extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        //String value = extras.getString(AskQuestions.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


        setContentView(R.layout.summary);

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //String value = "HELLO";

        TextView lblYes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yes_result);
        lblYes.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("value"));

        TextView lblNo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.no_result);
        lblNo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("value"));


    }


}
```

The error (app crashes):

[image: ScreenShot App Crash]

The consol output:

[2012-10-16 01:28:04 - QuizApp] Android Launch!
[2012-10-16 01:28:04 - QuizApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-16 01:28:04 - QuizApp] Performing com.example.quizapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-16 01:28:04 - QuizApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'firstDevice'
[2012-10-16 01:28:05 - QuizApp] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.quizapp' on port 8621
[2012-10-16 01:28:07 - QuizApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.quizapp/.MainActivity }
[2012-10-16 01:28:08 - QuizApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-10-16 01:28:08 - QuizApp] Starting activity com.example.quizapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-10-16 01:28:10 - QuizApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.quizapp/.MainActivity }
[2012-10-16 01:28:10 - QuizApp] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.quizapp' on port 8621
[2012-10-16 01:28:12 - QuizApp] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.quizapp' on port 8621

Logcat error (after restarting the eclipse):

```
10-16 02:17:34.469: D/AndroidRuntime(1496): Shutting down VM
10-16 02:17:34.469: W/dalvikvm(1496): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f68288)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     ... 11 more
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     at com.example.quizapp.AskQuestions.onYes(AskQuestions.java:56)
10-16 02:17:34.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1496):     ... 14 more
10-16 02:17:38.499: E/Trace(1604): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-16 02:17:39.020: D/gralloc_goldfish(1604): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: Just a guess. Try to get inside of your `onCreate()` instead of `onStart()`

Comment: @SpK did try that but nothing change.

Comment: please paste logs from logcat view.

Comment: Restart eclipse and run the app again. Sometimes LogCat doesn't show errors like some.Theme is missing etc..,

Comment: @Archie.bpgc thanks, now the logcat showed some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first paramater to putExtra() is a String with the package name of the application AND the name of the value, for instance "com.example.quizapp.yesValues" or "com.example.quizapp.noValues"

You then retrieve the values via

```
getIntent().getExtras().getInt("com.example.quizapp.yesValues", -1);
getIntent.getExtras().getInt("com.example.quizapp.noValues", -1);
```

note the second parameter in getInt() is the default value

Your second error is due to IndexOutOfBoundsException. You are trying to access an index that does not exist in your array at the line:

```
lblQuestion.setText(messages[messageNum]);
```

In your onYes() and onNo() methods. Notice right above it you check that messageNum >= messages.length, then immediately after you address the array by it. Do that inside of a check

```
if(messageNum < messages.length)
```

good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I dunno somewho this solution does not work with me. Getting to think I might have different problem than Intents. :/

Comment: that's useless. thats what all apps show when they crash. show your output from logcat, with the error and stack trace, etc...

Comment: Thats why i did not put the screenshot in frist place. There is no logcat error at all. the codes are good but the crashes from nowhere.

Comment: now the logcats showed some errors after restarting the eclipse.

Comment: Perfect. Thats was my problem! now it is working. Thank you so much, Khalid

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting Exception because of this line of code:

```
lblQuestion.setText(messages[messageNum]);
```

in the `onYes(View view);` method

```
messageNum value = 5;
```

where as the total items in the messages Array is 5

```
message.length() = 5;
```

Hence an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(this, Summary.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putInt("Integer", IntValue);
summaryIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(summaryIntent);
```

For Recieving the integer value use:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
mInt= b.getInt("Integer");
```

This code is working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an int value in a TextView. I think this may help:

```
    TextView lblYes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yes_result);
    lblYes.setText(Integer.toString(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("value")));
```

And you should put the extra in the bundle like this:

```
    Bundle bundleObj = new Bundle();     
    bundleObj.putInt("value", getYesCount()); 
    summaryIntent.putExtras(bundleObj);
```